# How to get all trigrams of a string in clojure

Tags: clojure

Suppose I have a string "This is a string". The tri-grams would be "Thi", "his", "is ", "s i" etc. I want to return a vector of all the trim-grams. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `partition` or `partition-all` depending on whether you are
interested also in the last "non-*tri*-grams":

```clj
user=> (doc partition)
-------------------------
clojure.core/partition
([n coll] [n step coll] [n step pad coll])
  Returns a lazy sequence of lists of n items each, at offsets step
  apart. If step is not supplied, defaults to n, i.e. the partitions
  do not overlap. If a pad collection is supplied, use its elements as
  necessary to complete last partition upto n items. In case there are
  not enough padding elements, return a partition with less than n items.
```

```clj
(user=> (doc partition-all)
-------------------------
clojure.core/partition-all
([n] [n coll] [n step coll])
  Returns a lazy sequence of lists like partition, but may include
  partitions with fewer than n items at the end.  Returns a stateful
  transducer when no collection is provided.
```

E.g.

```clj
user=> (partition 3 1 "This is a string")
((\T \h \i)
 (\h \i \s)
 (\i \s \space)
 (\s \space \i)
 (\space \i \s)
 (\i \s \space)
 (\s \space \a)
 (\space \a \space)
 (\a \space \s)
 (\space \s \t)
 (\s \t \r)
 (\t \r \i)
 (\r \i \n)
 (\i \n \g))
```

To get the strings back, join the chars:

```clj
user=> (map clojure.string/join (partition 3 1 "This is a string"))
("Thi"
 "his"
 "is "
 "s i"
 " is"
 "is "
 "s a"
 " a "
 "a s"
 " st"
 "str"
 "tri"
 "rin"
 "ing")
```

Or replace with `partition-all` accordingly:

```clj
user=> (map clojure.string/join (partition-all 3 1 "This is a string"))
("Thi"
 ; ...
 "rin"
 "ing"
 "ng"  ; XXX
 "g")  ; XXX
```